# Env not modify when loading module in modulefile

Tags: environment-variables, tcl, environment-modules, modulefile

I would like to load a module into a modulefile (to resolve dependencies).

MyModule:

```
#%Module########################################
##
##  Modulefile
#
proc ModulesHelp { } {
    puts stderr "Env for MyProg"
}
proc addPath {var val} {
    prepend-path $var $val
}
module load MyOtherModule 
addPath   PATH   /opt/MyModule/bin
```

MyOtherModule:

```
#%Module########################################
##
##  Modulefile
#
proc ModulesHelp { } {
    puts stderr "Env for MyOtherProg"
}
proc addPath {var val} {
    prepend-path $var $val
}
addPath   PATH   /opt/MyOtherModule/bin
```

When I run `module load MyModule`, both modules seem to be loaded but environment is not right :

```
$module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
  1) MyModule   2) MyOtherModule
$echo $PATH
/opt/MyModule/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

If I add the line `foreach p [array names env] { set tmp $env($p) }` or at least `set tmp $env(PATH)` in the MyModule after the `module load MyOtherModule` line, the environment is correctly modified. It also work fine if I don't use my function `addPath` but I use the `prepend-path` command directly, which is a bit annoying because I would like to do more things in the `addPath` function of course.

Anyone as an idea on what is going on and what I am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `prepend-path` is probably doing some “clever” stuff to manage a variable; what exactly it is is something I don't know and don't need to know, because we can solve it all using generic Tcl. To make your wrapping of it work, use `uplevel` to evaluate the code in the proper scope, though you need to consider whether to use the global scope (name `#0`) or the caller's scope (`1`, which is the default); they're the same when your procedure `addPath` is called from the global level, but otherwise can be *quite* different, and I don't know what other oddness is going on with the modules system processing.

To demonstrate, try this `addPath`:

```
proc addPath {var val} {
    puts stderr "BEFORE..."
    uplevel 1 [list prepend-path $var $val]
    puts stderr "AFTER..."
}
```

We use `list` to construct the thing to evaluate in the caller's scope, as it is guaranteed to generate substitution-free single-command scripts. (And valid lists too.) This is the whole secret to doing code generation in Tcl: keep it simple, use `list` to do any quoting required, call a helper procedure (with suitable arguments) when things get complicated, and use `uplevel` to control evaluation scope.

(NB: `upvar` can also be useful — it binds local variables to variables in another scope — but isn't what you're recommended to use here. I mention it because it's likely to be useful if you do anything more complex…)